# WordPress styling recent post

Tags: php, functions

Trying to replicate the theme shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcahM.png.

As you can see on the screenshot the first post is black and the second post is a grey colour.

My progress so far is just at Filtering the post by day I am confused on how to change the color of the background on each link.

My Functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{ 

if ( $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() ) {
    $q->set(  'posts_per_page', 10 );
    $q->set( 'cat', 2 );
    $date_query = array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
     );
     $q->set( 'date_query', $date_query );
}

});
```

What's happening on the screenshot is it looks like the first post is set as

```
<div class="track row-1">
<div class="track-details">
<!--mp3-->
<a class="track-title" href="http://www.example.com">POST TITLE</a>
</div>
</div>
```

While the second post is set as

```
<div class="track row-0">
<div class="track-details">
<!--mp3-->
<a class="track-title" href="http://www.example.com">POST TITLE</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just list them as a list regularly, and style them with css

```
li:nth-child(even) { background: #000 }
li:nth-child(odd) { background: #CCC }
```

If you are worried about browser support you could add different classes when you're populating the list in PHP using $i or something like

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
  echo '<li class="'.($i %2 == 0 ? 'blackrow' : 'greyrow').'">'.$title.'</li>';
}
```

Or if you're using while() then just do `$i = 0;` before the while and add `$i++` at the end of the while loop.

The php code probably has some errors because I have no means to test now and just threw that up from the top of the dome, and I'm not so great with code. But it should give you an idea.

Comment: Does not give me an idea just confused me a lot more..

Comment: Oh, sorry then, you do have a populated list already? And if so, how do you output it and where? I just meant that if you have a list like that that is somewhere close like [[this]](http://codepen.io/jimihenrik/pen/MwYKBz) you could do that just by CSS.